# Are this two random variables independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

> Let me take $a<b$ and define $\Omega=[a,b]$, let $\Bbb{P}$ the lebesgue measure on $\Omega$. Then let me define $X(\omega)=2\omega$ if $\omega \in [a,\xi]$ for some $a<\xi<b$, and $X(\omega)=\omega^2$ if $\omega \in (\xi, b]$.
> Now I want to compute $\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{1}_{[a,\xi]})$.

I know how to do it but my question is, can't I say that $\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{1}_{[a,\xi]})=\Bbb{E}(X)\Bbb{P}(\Bbb{1}_{[a,\xi]})$ I think this is not true since $X$ depends on the interval, but somehow I am a bit confused since if I take $\Bbb{E}(X\cdot c)=c\Bbb{E}(X)$ for some constant $c$ but in our case the characteristic function $\Bbb{1}_{[a,\xi]}$ is also like the constants $0,1$.

So could maybe someone explain this to me why it isn't independent anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are not independent.

$EX1_{[a,\xi]}=\int_a^{\xi} X(\omega)d\omega =\int_a^{\xi} 2\omega d\omega=\xi^{2}-a^{2}$. [You can see that this is not equal to $(EX)(E1_{[a,\xi]})$].

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Are there cases where the characteristic function is independent?

Comment: @user1294729 Yes, $X=2\omega 1_{[a,\xi]}+\omega^{2}(1-1_{[a,\xi]})$ so you don't even expect independence.

Comment: Your over-simplified idea  of independenee is not acceptable. You have to go by the technical definition of independence.

Comment: ah okey thanks.